# Need a better Live Log Viewer for NLog, Log4Net and Enterprise Library

Tags: viewer

I need a better Live Log Viewer that supports NLog, Log4net and Enterprise Library.  The Viewer must constantly be running in live mode for our operation guys.  So far the ones that we've tried always run out of memory and we always need to restart them.  I need a Viewer that can either remove unwanted stale messages or roll them over to a log file automatically.  I know this is a tall order.  So far no luck. We will even pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

I use the ReflectInsight Viewer. http://www.reflectsoftware.com/

We use Enterprise Library and Log4net logging at work which produce text log files. Previously I would use a number of tail logging programs to show me new messages that came into the files, but didn't provide much filtering, searching capabilities.

By adding a reference to the ReflectInsight Logging Extensions https://insightextensions.codeplex.com and updating my existing logging configuration, I was able to send my logged messages to the ReflectInsight viewer and view them in real-time. I was then able to search, filter, bookmark, and view my messages.

I could then save the results to another file...containing only what I needed and filtering out the noise from other applications.

I hope this helps you as it did me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LogGrok for viewing NLOG logs?

It supports filter the log by any field for MSI, VB and NLOG, configurable highlighteres(some are already pre-configured), multiple search results (supporting Regex).

Utility supports large log files and has customizable docking windows UI.

LogGrok is opensource, you can add features you need by yourself(or ask project team to add it for you).

Project documentation can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/pekabon/LogGrok)

Answer (score 0):

I use LogExpert http://logexpert.codeplex.com/ it is free, and it has some very powerful features. I have only ran into one or two minor bugs. Features include, Filtering, Search, Color coded phrases, regular expressions, filter to tab (creating new log files from distilled results).

All in all really well done, and the developer needs help to keep it going!